# How to generate the html report in intern js

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, intern

We use intern JS for the automation of functional tests, but we can't generate a report html

I used locvhtml https://theintern.github.io/intern/#reporter-lcov but it just gets me an empty html report
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Intern doesn't currently include a reporter that generates HTML test result reports as files. Its built in HTML reporter is DOM-based and only generates in-browser reports, and while the lcovhtml reporter generates file-based HTML reports, they're for code coverage rather than test results.

Comment: but i want to generate somtheing like this https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/09/12/intern-2-1-released/

Comment: Intern's HTML reporter is intended to be used with the browser client, which is used for running unit tests in a browser. It won't be useful for functional tests, which do run tests in browsers, but do all of their report generation in Node.